# Specific option in select adds options in next select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have two `<select>`s, the first `<select>` has a bunch of `<option>`s however the second `<select>` has none. I would like to have each `<option>` in the first `<select>` to add different options in the second `<select>`, preferably with JavaScript/jQuery.

**e.g.**

```
<select id="firstSelect">
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="addOptions">
<!--Add stuff here!-->
</select>
```

And what would happen in the code above is selecting option 1 would add options A, B, and C to `#adoptions` while option 2 would add options D and E to `#adoptions`, and option 3 would add options F, G, H, and I to `#adoptions`.

EDIT: I have tried this:

```
function dropdownChecker() {
switch($('select#weapon').val()) {
    case "1":
        $("#dropSpace").append('<option>My option</option>');
        break;
    case "2":
        $("#dropSpace".append('<option>Second Option</option>'))
        break;
}
$(document).ready(dropdownChecker());
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward using event listeners. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: This is way too broad, especially since you are not even showing the slightest own approach or attempt. Please go read [ask], and then start your research using sth. like this, https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+nested+selects

Comment: Did the code you tried not work? What was the result? Did you get an error message?

Comment: There were no error codes, just nothing happening in the second <select>.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `array` of options that you want to insert in second `select`. After this, based on the selection of value from the first dropdown, you have to create and populate options in the second dropdown using this small code:

```
$.each(optionsArray, function(key, value) {
  $('#addOptions')
    .append($("<option></option>")
      .attr("value", value)
      .text(value));
});
```

Below is the complete example:

```js
$("#firstSelect").on('change', function() {
  var optionsArray = '';
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case "1":
      optionsArray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
      break;
    case "2":
      optionsArray = ['D', 'E'];
      break;
    case "3":
      optionsArray = ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
      break;
  }
  $('#addOptions').empty();
  $.each(optionsArray, function(key, value) {
    $('#addOptions')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value)
        .text(value));
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#firstSelect").trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="firstSelect">
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="addOptions">
<!--Add stuff here!-->
</select>
```

Comment: Strange. When I run the code snippet on the website it inevitably works, however I've tried plenty of different things and it won't run for me off of this site. I'm using the program Brackets and I'm running the page in Opera, not sure what's going on here.